# Resharper: Enable warnings on C# 7.0 features?

Tags: resharper, c#-7.0

My question is the opposite of just about every question I have found online.

I want to **enable** C# 7.0 warnings/errors in Resharper (running in VS2017, release just installed today.)

I need to do this because the project I am working on will be published to my workplace's server, and their CI throws fatal errors when C# 7.0 features are used (`R# C# 7.0 language feature`), so I can't use them (they won't accept any project that fails fatally with their CI.)

They're using Resharper CLI in the CI. So I want to make my Resharper throw the same errors, so I can quickly locate and eliminate C# 7.0 features. My Resharper shows the project as being clean (other than some minor "it might be a problem but it's not for me" things), so I have no fatal errors or even warnings about C# 7.0 when I run a code analysis.

Every question I have seen so far is asking about how to **disable** warnings about C# 7.0. My Resharper is not throwing any warnings or errors, while the one on our CI is.

I've looked through the options but can't find any obvious "C# 7.0" options. I've looked for something like "maximum supported language/throw an error if language feature in later version is used/etc" but I can't seem to find anything.

Edit: Web.config codedom section:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

It's definitely set to language version 6...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure which C# version the build engine uses for each project by right clicking on the project, select `Properties`, Select the `Build` section, click on `Advanced...`, set `Language version` to whichever version your CI server works with. Once you do this the build will fail when you build locally on any C#7.0 features.

[image]

Alternately you could try to get your CI server upgraded to work with C#7.0.

Comment: "Alternately you could try to get your CI server upgraded to work with C#7.0." This to my mind is the "correct answer" :)

Comment: @DavidArno You are right, however I am sure it is far more difficult to get the CI server changed that would affect everyone who uses it as opposed to just changing your own projects language version.

Comment: @DavidArno In a perfect world, yes. In the reality of bureaucracy, not so much a useful answer. :-)

Comment: @DavidArno Plus, if you still have devs working with VS2015, then you can't switch to C#7. We have some who have an Ultimate licence for 2015, but can't afford to replace it with one for 2017. Understandably, they don't want to downgrade to a lower version of VS, so we're also stuck with C#6

Answer (score 0):

The Resharper language rules and Studio rules lie in different places.
Studio (and Roslyn) rules you can find in project settings.
Resharper keeps warning rules in  the **[ProjectName].csproj.DotSettings** file.

Xml Node:

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">CSharp70</s:String>
```

This file can be safely deleted to get things back to default.

File for warnings 6.0 will be something like that:

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
     <s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/CSharpLanguageProject/LanguageLevel/@EntryValue">CSharp60</s:String>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```